# How to implement the idatastore interface in xaf

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I have a non-persistent object in my aplication. Is it possible to make it persistent object for XPo if i implement the interface IdataStore?

Comment: It all looks like we have already discussed this topic with you in 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T717749/where-do-you-convert-your-query-language-into-standard-sql-in-the-framework and 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T712436/how-to-make-custom-dataprovider-with-web-service

If my guess is correct, I suggest that we continue this discussion there. I doubt anybody will answer you here based on the current incomplete source problem/ultimate goal description. Thanks.

Comment: @DennisGaravsky Thanks for the answer, your guess is correct, but you answer there long, and just say , Read documentation,and I read it already many times, and told your colleagues that there are Uvas there methodological inaccuracies. And with pleasure I will continue to communicate with you there. I have to do my project as planned, but I spend a lot of time to understand the logic of your framework, but the framework is ultimately good and convenient.

Comment: @DennisGaravsky Although I have a large application that works with a standard data provider. But I need to make the simplest of my data provider, without connection string, very simple, I just need to populate data already created persistent xpo objects. I would be happy to get your advice in private.